# Is there any way I can extract frames [frame-rate = 5] from a video with the help of OpenCV python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, frame-rate

I was able to extract frames from a video file of 297 secs with the help of the code below, however I only need frames at frame-rate = 5. The extracted images should be at 5 frame rates and the total frames should be 298. Video file is 30fps and in mp4 format.

```
import cv2 
import os 

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("/content/Dataset/video.mp4") 

try:        
    if not os.path.exists('/content/data'): 
        os.makedirs('/content/data')  
except OSError: 
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data') 

currentframe = 0

while(True):  
    ret,frame = vid.read()   
    if ret: 
        name = '/content/data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'  
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame) 
        currentframe += 1
    if currentframe == 298:
      break

vid.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print('Completed')
```

Comment: OK, so essentially you want the first 60 seconds of the video at a frame rate of 5 frames per second?

Comment: no for whole 297 secs at frame rate 5

Comment: Ok, so you want a total of 297 * 5 = 1485 frames, correct?

Comment: actually I am not sure, I am posting the original question from where I got

Comment: "Train.csv: Contains human-generated labels for 298 frames [Frame-rate =5] from the training video" This was the question , and actually I am not sure what they have asked?

Comment: I guess you'd better go and get clarification from whoever asked the question.

Comment: Sir, what I have understood is after extracting the first frame the next frame must be 5 frames apart and so on and the total frames should be 298, I now fully sure, please help me